# How to host two domains in a single box

Tags: node.js, apache

I have a web domain running in my local, say test.com using apache pointing to a node server port, ie 4000

Now I wanted to set up another sub domain, say subdomain.test.com in the same box using a different node port.

Right now, test.com is working in the way like, hitting apache first and redirecting to node server using a redirect rule entry in the hpptd-proxy.conf like below

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:4000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4000/
```

Please let me know if any one has any idea on the above issue.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

How about using virtualhost for redirect process

```
<VirtualHost subdomain.test.com:80>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost test.com:80>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:4000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4000/
</VirtualHost>
```